# Null/undefined return in WordPress AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I really need help on this one. I've been looking at it for hours and been getting nowehere. I am working with ajax in WordPress and this is kind of my first time doing so.

I have a function in my code that utlimately ends with the following:

```
echo json_encode($aData);
```

I then have code in my js file written as follows:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    url: "path/to/admin-ajax.php", //AJAX file 
    // dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    // contentType: 'application/json',     
    data: { action: "process_chart_data" },             
    success: function(chartData) {
        //Code, that need to be executed when data arrives after
        // successful AJAX request execution
        console.log("SUCCESS");         
        console.log(chartData);  

    }
});
```

You will notice the comments in the above code. When I view chartData in the console I get this:

```
{"title":"R=3+","dates":["06\/04\/2014","11\/05\/2014","15\/06\/2014","27\/07\/2014","17\/08\/2014","28\/09\/2014","05\/10\/2014","19\/10\/2014","09\/11\/2014","23\/11\/2014","14\/12\/2014"],"series":[{"data":[[1396738800000,284],[1399762800000,350],[1402786800000,212],[1406415600000,296],[1408230000000,220],[1411858800000,253],[1412463600000,200],[1413673200000,310],[1415491200000,180],[1416700800000,156],[1418515200000,290]],"name":"Bulls"}]}0
```

However when I uncomment the dataType and contentType this outputs a 0.

My issue is I am trying to access properties of the returned array such as chartData.title but all I get is 'undefined'.

I have looked at this from a few different approaches but after a few hours I have had to throw my hands up. I would be greatly appreciative for any assistance people might be able to provide here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the output you have provided is the correct one but do you notice the '0' character at the end of your string?

```
{"title":"R=3+","dates":["06\/04\/2014","11\/05\/2014","15\/06\/2014","27\/07\/2014","17\/08\/2014","28\/09\/2014","05\/10\/2014","19\/10\/2014","09\/11\/2014","23\/11\/2014","14\/12\/2014"],"series":[{"data":[[1396738800000,284],[1399762800000,350],[1402786800000,212],[1406415600000,296],[1408230000000,220],[1411858800000,253],[1412463600000,200],[1413673200000,310],[1415491200000,180],[1416700800000,156],[1418515200000,290]],"name":"Bulls"}]}0
```

That is enough to cause the JSON parser to fail.

Also, don't use the `contentType` property like that since [you don't send any JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), you should remove that line altogether.

Comment: Yes, there is a zero at the end there. Is that me adding that somehow? I don't send any JSON to the request but that is what is coming back. So in that instance is it still correct to drop the contentType property?

Comment: You should call the `exit` function (technically a language construct but never mind that) right after you output the response. The `contentType` property is totally unnecessary to be specified since, just like the documentation that I have linked to states, you should alter that property only when you are sending data in the JSON format. The `dataType` is the one you need to let know jQuery how to handle the response NOT the `contentType`.

Comment: Thanks. I was unhappy getting my code to work without really understanding what was going on. You've been a big help in that regard.